# Make vbulletin post visible only to author

Tags: permissions, forum, vbulletin

I'm using vbulletin 4.1.8 and I want to make a post visible only to the author. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Admincp > Forums & Moderators**

- Select the forum /subforum you want
- Select the usergroup you want
- `Can View Thread Content` -> check "yes"
- `Can View Others' Threads` -> check "no"